# how to use bash output as variable

Tags: linux, bash, curl, scripting, system-administration

I am creating a job that would first initiate an API checking what is the next available ip in a subnet with some parameters.

Then i want to run "ping" check on the output (that is an IP), then also telnet to ports 22 80 3389 on the same output,

how can i insert all the CURL output in to a variable so i can continue the script running ping and telnet checks before giving an indication that the ip is really "Available" - i have tried many failed syntaxes in the last 2 days :) thank you.

so:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --stderr -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "query=ip" -d "string=$1" -u 'username:password' https://device42.xxxxxxxxx/api/1.0/search/ --insecure | awk '{print "Avaliable",$9,$10,$11}'
[[ -z "$1" ]] && echo "Please Enter IP" ||
```

the api returns this atm:

```
available: Yes ip: 10.120.34.11
```

Comment: This is the second question in a short period that is looking for `variable=$(command)`. Most tutorials that i've seen (e.g. https://guide.bash.academy/expansions/ or https://www.learnshell.org/en/Variables or many others) seem to cover this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl --stderr -i` is invalid. You might want `curl --stderr - -i`.

Try substitution ` with command output in any shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`curl --stderr - -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "query=ip" -d "string=$1" -u 'username:password' https://device42.xxxxxxxxx/api/1.0/search/ --insecure | awk '{print "Avaliable",$9,$10,$11}'`
[[ -z "$var" ]] && echo "Please Enter IP" ||
```

Or with another command output substitution syntax

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(curl --stderr - -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "query=ip" -d "string=$1" -u 'username:password' https://device42.xxxxxxxxx/api/1.0/search/ --insecure | awk '{print "Avaliable",$9,$10,$11}')
[[ -z "$var" ]] && echo "Please Enter IP" ||
```

Comment: Every POSIX compatible shell should support `$( ... )`, this is not specific to bash.

Comment: thank you.

when running this i get no output - 
-----------
#!/bin/bash
var=`curl --stderr - -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "query=ip" -d "string=$1" -u 'username:password' https://device42.xxxxxxxxx/api/1.0/search/ --insecure | awk '{print "Avaliable",$9,$10,$11}'`
[[ -z "$var" ]] && echo "Please Enter IP" ||
-----------
adding echo "$var" dosent work

Comment: What output do you get if remove `| awk '{print "Avaliable",$9,$10,$11}'`?

Comment: thank you. i got it! :) the issue was with  the structure not the awk. much appreciated 

now i run-----------#!/bin/bash
var=`curl --stderr -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "query=ip" -d "string=$1" -u 'user:password' https://device42.xxxxxxxxxxx/api/1.0/search/ --insecure`
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
         echo "Please Enter IP"
        exit 1
else
        echo $var | awk '{print $8,$9,$10,$11}' | tr -d '{}()[]",'
fi